# extracting from 2 dimensional array and creating a hash with array values

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a 2 dimensional array

```
v = [ ["ab","12"], ["ab","31"], ["gh","54"] ]
```

The first element of the subarray of v will have repeating elements, such as `"ab"`. I want to create a hash that puts the key as the first element of the subarray, and values as an array of corresponding second elements from `v`.

please advice.

Further, I want this, h={"ab"=>["12","31"],"gh"=>["54"]} and then I want to return h.values, such that the array [["12","31"],["54"]] is returned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
v.inject(Hash.new{|h,k|h[k]=[]}) { |h, (k, v)| h[k] << v ; h}
```

What it does:

- [inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) (also called `reduce`) is a [fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29). Wikipedia defines folds like this: *"a family of higher-order functions that analyze a recursive data structure and recombine through use of a given combining operation the results of recursively processing its constituent parts, building up a return value*".
- The block form of [Hash.new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-new) takes two arguments, the hash itself and the key. If your default argument is a mutable object, you have to set the default this way, otherwise all keys will point to the same array instance.
- In `inject`'s block, we get two arguments, the hash and the current value of the iteration. Since this is a two element array, `(k, v)` is used to destructure the latter into two variables.
- Finally we add each value to the array for its key and return the entire hash for the next iteration.

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for you should accept it with the little tick mark below the up-/downvote arrows.

Comment: I undertand most part of the code. Please explain this. In the inject>parameter>block what is the h,k and how it works?

Comment: It's explained in the third bullet point... `inject`'s second argument would be the current element of the collection `v`. Since those are two element arrays themselves, I split them up in two different variables, called `k` (for key) and `v` (for value), but of course the names are arbitrary.

Comment: And when I do (v.inject(Hash.new{|h,k|h[k]=[]}) { |h, (k, v)| h[k] << v ; h}).values, it only returns the last value. Why?

Comment: It returns `[["12", "31"], ["54"]]` for me, are you sure you are using the same test data?

Comment: Michael Kohl, I have rectified the problem. You are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
v.inject({­}) do |res,­ ar|
  res[ar.fir­st] ||= []
  res[ar.fir­st] << ar.la­st
  res
end
```

Comment: I want this, h={"ab"=>["12","31"],"gh"=>["54"]} and then I want to return h.values, such that the array [["12","31"],["54"]] is returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
v = [ ["ab","12"], ["ab","31"], ["gh","54"] ]
```

This gets you a hash, where the keys are the 
unique first elements from the sub arrays.

```
h = v.inject({}) { |c,i| (c[i.first] ||= []) << i.last; c }
```

This turns that hash back into an array, just in case you need the array of arrays format.

```
arr = h.collect { |k,v| [k,v] }
```

Comment: Hey Ctcherry, please explain what's happening here. I am new to ruby.

Comment: Hey Ctcheery, what this does is h={"ab"=>"12","ab"=>"31","gh"=>"54"} but what I want is this h={"ab"=>["12","31"],"gh"=>["54"]} and then I want to return h.values, such that the array [["12","31"],["54"]] is returned.