# Creating Hash of Hash from an Array of Array

Tags: ruby

I have an array:

```
values = [["branding", "color", "blue"],
          ["cust_info", "customer_code", "some_customer"],
          ["branding", "text", "custom text"]]
```

I am having trouble tranforming it to  hash as follow:

```
{
"branding"  => {"color"=>"blue", "text"=>"custom text"},
"cust_info" => {"customer_code"=>"some customer"}
}
```

Comment: Array#inject is useful here. Basically, start with a new hash (passed into collect) and key adding to it each item. See http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/03/ruby-inject.html for a very similar example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use default hash values to create something more legible than inject:

```
h = Hash.new {|hsh, key| hsh[key] = {}}
values.each {|a, b, c| h[a][b] = c}
```

Obviously, you should replace the `h` and `a, b, c` variables with your domain terms.

Bonus: If you find yourself needing to go N levels deep, check out autovivification:

```
fun = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }
fun[:a][:b][:c][:d] = :e
# fun == {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>{:d=>:e}}}}
```

Or an overly-clever one-liner using `each_with_object`:

```
silly = values.each_with_object(Hash.new {|hsh, key| hsh[key] = {}}) {|(a, b, c), h| h[a][b] = c}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using [Enumerable#inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

```
values = [["branding", "color", "blue"],
          ["cust_info", "customer_code", "some_customer"],
          ["branding", "text", "custom text"]]

# r is the value we are are "injecting" and v represents each
# value in turn from the enumerable; here we create
# a new hash which will be the result hash (res == r)
res = values.inject({}) do |r, v|
    group, key, value = v     # array decomposition
    r[group] ||= {}           # make sure group exists
    r[group][key] = value     # set key/value in group
    r                         # return value for next iteration (same hash)
end
```

There are several different ways to write this; I think the above is relatively simple. See [extracting from 2 dimensional array and creating a hash with array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715833/extracting-from-2-dimensional-array-and-creating-a-hash-with-array-values?rq=1) for using a Hash (i.e. grouper) with "auto vivification".

Comment: what is the syntax of *v?

Comment: @pchu Whoops, I forget it (the "splat operator") is not required in Ruby to force array decomposition in an assignment. That will coerce the value to an Array on the RHS like that, but it's already an array .. corrected code. (Although `group, key, value = *v` is also legal in modern Ruby, it doesn't add any benefit in this case.)

Comment: Thanks it works.  First time I see the splat operator.  Cannot believe Ruby has an operator call splat.

Answer (score 0):

Less elegant but easier to understand:

```
hash = {}
values.each do |value|
  if hash[value[0]] 
    hash[value[0]][value[1]] = value[2]
  else
    hash[value[0]] = {value[1] => value[2]}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
values.inject({}) { |m, (k1, k2, v)| m[k1] = { k2 => v }.merge m[k1] || {}; m }
```